# Upgraded PSU x1.25 and still getting power off at maximum load

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, diagnostic

Some tasks that involve serious number crunching CPU+GPU or gaming in VR cause my computer to just shutdown abruptly. So i had to live with CPU load bound to 80%. That solved the problem but of course i didn't pay for that CPU to have it throttled down. I decided that the problem is my (HEC600TC5WK) PSU getting its over current tripped and upgraded to Corsair RM750x (750W). It didn't fix anything. I get power offs just as easily when running stress test. (The power goes out with a loud relay clank  inside PSU). So I am pretty desperate now. I tried different outlets etc. I heard Ausus motherboards have buggy surge protection, but that seems impossible to shut off.

- ASUS PRIME Z370-P
- Intel Core i7-8700K (not overclocked)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
- Corsair RM750x

Comment: If you've verified it's power, and not heat, that's causing the shutdown, the issue is the power you're consuming off of one or more of the voltage output channels (+3.3V, +5V, +12V1, +12V2, -12V, +5VSB).  To resolve, review the voltage output circuits connected to your motherboard and components and compare them to your PSU's manual, checking each circuit to find the one that's overloaded (_**"circuit"_:** voltage cables for the same voltage output channel).  **Ohm's Law:** V[oltage] x A[mperage] = P[ower] (Wattage) (`V*A=P`)

Answer (score 1):

If it really is down to CPU drawing too much power, you can try undervolting the CPU using your BIOS settings. For electronic circuits, power usage goes up with the square of voltage, so a small voltage reduction can result in a large reduction in power / heat. Most Intel CPUs that don't come pre-overclocked from the factory have a fair amount of margin for error in them for undervolting. Somewhere around a ~10% voltage reduction may well be achievable, with a corresponding ~20% reduction in power draw and heat.

It is also worth checking airflow in your system and making sure some of the power components on your motherboard aren't overheating.